# Filter http request in .net

Tags: c#, java, asp.net

Is There in ASP.NET and C# something like Java filter? I need to intercept all request and check if user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Check out the ASP.NET Http Module features. You can plug these in via you web.config configuration.

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649096.aspx

However, perhaps out of the box [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.ASPX) (which itself is implemented in ASP.NET by an HTTP module) may be of value to you.